# Processing URLs found in HTML page

Tags: java, html, url

I have a `HTML` page. I parse it using `jsoup`, here is the part of the code

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);

org.jsoup.select.Elements images = doc.select("[src]");

for(org.jsoup.nodes.Element img : images) {
    // Here I need to determine the type of the URL and convert it to absolute URL
}
```

I need to change all URLs inside this HTML to absolute URLs.
The problem is that, `src` attribute of `<img> </img>` could be of type, if host if `www.example.com`:

```
 1. http://www.example.com/images/1.png
 2. http://example.com/images/1.png
 3. www.example.com/images/1.png
 4. example.com/images/1.png
 5. /example.com/images/1.png
 6. //example.com/images/1.png
 7. /images/1.png
```

I came up with this list, while I was testing, so I should support them all. So I need some function which will outputs me the absolute URL(`http://www.example.com/images/1.png`) for all inputs listed above.
The problem is even complicated when the URL is for resource from another location, for example `haha.com/images/1.png`.

So I need a way to determine the type of URL, something like:

- relative(`/images/1.png`);
- absolute(`http://example.com/images/1.png`);
- protocol relative(`example.com/images/1.png`).

What is the best approach to solve this problem in java? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the methods available from the DOM. Specifically: document.URL

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp